# How to do automatic OpenGL error checking using GLEW?

Tags: c, opengl, macros, c-preprocessor, glew

I was recently trying to implement automatic error checking after each OpenGL function call. I considered wrapping each OpenGL function in a caller like this:

```
CheckForErrors(glCreateBuffers(1, &VBO));
```

But I saw that GLEW already uses its own function wrapper:

```
#define GLEW_GET_FUN(x) x
```

So I decided to edit it instead of writting my own function wrapper:

```
    #ifndef GLEW_GET_FUN
    #ifdef DEBUG
        #define GLEW_GET_FUN(x) while (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR);\
                x; {\
                GLenum error = glGetError();\
                if (error != GL_NO_ERROR) {\
                    printf("[GLEW]: OpenGL error(s) occured while calling %s in %s (line %s):", #x, __FILE__, __LINE__);\
                    do printf(" %d", error); while (error = glGetError());\
                    printf("\n");\
                    __debugbreak();\
                }
    #else
        #define GLEW_GET_FUN(x) x
    #endif
    #endif
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't compile. For example this function call:

```
GLuint vertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

Gets changed to this by the preprocessor:

```
    GLuint vertexShaderID = while (glGetError() != GL_NO_ERROR); __glewCreateShader; { GLenum error = glGetError(); if (error != 0) { printf("[GLEW]: OpenGL error(s) occured while calling %s in %s (line %s):", "__glewCreateShader", "main.cpp", 51); do printf(" %d", error); while (error = glGetError()); printf("\n"); __debugbreak(); }(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

There are 2 problems here:

1. The statement starts with a while loop, so it cannot return the value.
2. The parentheses with function parameters are placed after the whole thing and not right after the function call.

I don't know how to overcome those problems and I will appreciate help.

## Notes

- I am aware of the `glDebugMessageCallback()` function, but it is only availble in OpenGL 4.3+ which is a rather new and partially insupported yet version.
- I cannot remove the while loop at the beginning, because I have to clear all errors before calling the function (unless there is a diffrent way to do this).
- I am trying to do something like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBbPWSOQ0-w), but without using a separate function wrapper.

Comment: [MCVE] of what you have tried? How does it "not work"?

Comment: "*Which is a very new version.*" If by "very new" you mean "4+ years ago". The amount of available hardware that doesn't support either the extension or the core feature is pretty minimal, and I wouldn't expect my code to run on a platform whose drivers are that far out of date.

Comment: @NicolBolas by very new I mean that my integrated Intel graphics card does not suport it, so I think that other peoples' cards may not suport it either.

Comment: @YanB.: "*I cannot remove the while loop at the beginning, because I have to clear all errors before calling the function (unless there is a diffrent way to do this).*" Um, why? If you clear out all errors before every function call, then errors that appear after a call will be because of that specific call. Errors do not manifest out of nothing. If every OpenGL call is so wrapped, then the initial `while` loop is unnecessary.

Comment: @NicolBolas There is a possibility that an OpenGL function may be called outside of GLEW. For example someone could call __glewCreateBuffers() directly without using the wrapper for some weird reason. Such a case must be also considered.

Comment: @YanB.: But you don't consider them; you just *discard* any such errors. At least if you print them, you can have a chance at figuring out that something has gone wrong, with a general idea of where, even if you mis-attribute the source of the error.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're right. Instead of discarding them I will print them out too as "caused by an unknown source". Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how to overcome those problems

You can't. What you want to do is simply not viable in the way you want to do it. You cannot turn an expression (which is what a function call is) into a statement (or rather, a series of statements) and have that work everywhere. It will only work in circumstances where the expression is used as a statement.

If you are unwilling to just regularly insert error checking code into your application, and are unable to use the modern debug messaging API, then the standard solution is to use an external tool to find and report errors. RenderDoc can detect OpenGL errors, for example. It allows you to log every OpenGL call and can report errors anytime they occur.

Comment: @YanB.: As I said, "What you want to do is simply not viable **in the way you want to do it.**" The `GLCall` macro is doing something different from what you're trying to do. It has a similar goal, but it doesn't work the way you're wanting to make things work.

Answer (score 0):

As Nicol Bolas said, it is impossible to do it the way I originally wanted, but I will describe why this is the case and what can be done instead.

## The Problem

GLEW wraps only the **name** of the function with GLEW_GET_FUN(), so function parameters will always be placed after the end of the define as they are not included in it:

```
//In code:    
glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
//After preprocessing:
{stuff generated by GLEW_GET_FUN}(1, &VBO);
```

Preprocessing isn't very inteligent so it will just put the function parameters at the end.

## Other Solutions

1. As described in the question, one could use `glDebugMessageCallback()` if availble.
2. Wrap each function with a custom wrapper. Not automatic at all, but if someone is interested [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBbPWSOQ0-w) is a great tutorial on how to make one.